# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, json

I've an encoded stringifyed JSON object stored in database, I decoded it and loaded it and tried to parse it into an object But I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
>       at JSON.parse ()

Code:

```
var attr = new Object();
attr = JSON.parse(code[1].replace(/"/g, "'"));
```

Object decoded:

> [{'inputs':0,'type':'variable'},{'inputD':0,'type':'variable'},{'inputI':0,'type':'variable'},{'paras':0,'type':'variable'},{'headers':0,'type':'variable'},{'menus':0,'type':'variable'},{'lists':0,'type':'variable'},{'divs':0,'type':'variable'},{'links':0,'type':'variable'},{'images':0,'type':'variable'},{'elemName':'{}','type':'object'},{'borders':[],'type':'array'},{'nested':[],'type':'array'},{'ribbons':[],'type':'array'},{'tooltips':[],'type':'array'},{'gradColors':'{}','type':'object'},{'events':'{}','type':'object'},{'sTarget':'{}','type':'object'},{'sMain':'{}','type':'object'},{'orignalStyle':'{}','type':'object'},{'objNewStyle':'{}','type':'object'},{'functions':'{}','type':'object'},{'reverse':'{}','type':'object'},{'reverseFunction':'{}','type':'object'},{'scDetails':'{}','type':'object'}]

Comment: What do "encoded" and "decoded" mean? Why are you replacing double quotes with single quotes? What does the original object look like?

Comment: It's simply not JSON, as that uses only double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [not valid](http://www.json.org/) json string. Its values and keys should be surrounded with double quotes (not single). So when you do `.replace(/"/g, "'")` you basically break the JSON standard.

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

Comment: Please paste the string you're trying to parse. Is `code[1]`  the array you paste `[{"inp`...?

Comment: Thanks it worked! There was a (') at the first of the object

Answer (score 5):

I have same error, @Philipp Zitzmann is correct.
You must valid json string at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

valid json string must have double quote.

```
JSON.parse({"u1":1000,"u2":1100})       // will be ok
```

no quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({u1:1000,u2:1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

single quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({'u1':1000,'u2':1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON should be wrapped in double quotes like:
{"inputs":0,"type":"variable"}

This is a useful Tool for validating:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: JSON.parse({"u1":1000,"u2":1100}) will be ok

Comment: JSON.parse({u1:1000,u2:1100}) failed

Answer (score 1):

A related one. Today I hit the same error. An example is below:

Correct

```
JSON.parse( "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]" )
```

Incorrect

```
JSON.parse( "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..." )
```

Note the 3 dots (...), because a tool showed only few numbers in array, and gave ... for rest.

In other words, string passed to `JSON.parse()` is invalid, so it gave error.

But it can be any other similar error.

For example, (may be) `JSON.parse( "true" )` is correct but `JSON.parse( "tr" )` fails, etc.